# Orientation Portrait in navigation Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiinterfaceorientation

I try to force navigationController to be in orientation Portrait on my application. But I solved the problem by subclassing the navigationController class by this way :

```
    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    if (self.visibleViewController && [self.visibleViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(shouldAutorotate)])
    {
        return [self.visibleViewController shouldAutorotate];
    }
    return YES;
}

    - (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
    {
        if (self.visibleViewController && [self.visibleViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(supportedInterfaceOrientations)])
        {
            return [self.visibleViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
        }
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }
```

So all my controller inherits to this. But my problem is when I start my application with my iPhone in landscape mode, my viewController not respect the interfaceorientationlandscape. But when I turn my iPhone it's works and not change if the orientation changes. 
I search how can I force my orientation to change if is not in portrait in viewDidLoad or if possible in viewDidAppear.

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to have this app-wide**

[image: Where to set the orientation modes]

You can get there by clicking on the corresponding menu item:
[image: Where to find the configuration menu]

---

**Otherwise if you want to set this for one ViewController only**

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
     return YES; // or NO
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft; // or UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight or UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
     return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape; // or UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait
}
```

Comment: Yes I do this in all app but all my app is in Portrait I just want Landscape for slideshow images, but I return, all my app is in landscape

Comment: Yes I do this in all controllers what I want but doesn't work when I back !